# How does the forward method get called in this pyTorch conv net?

Tags: neural-network, pytorch

In this example network from [pyTorch tutorial](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/neural_networks_tutorial.html)

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F


class Net(nn.Module):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        # 1 input image channel, 6 output channels, 3x3 square convolution
        # kernel
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(1, 6, 3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(6, 16, 3)
        # an affine operation: y = Wx + b
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(16 * 6 * 6, 120)  # 6*6 from image dimension
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(120, 84)
        self.fc3 = nn.Linear(84, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        # Max pooling over a (2, 2) window
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv1(x)), (2, 2))
        # If the size is a square you can only specify a single number
        x = F.max_pool2d(F.relu(self.conv2(x)), 2)
        x = x.view(-1, self.num_flat_features(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = F.relu(self.fc2(x))
        x = self.fc3(x)
        return x

    def num_flat_features(self, x):
        size = x.size()[1:]  # all dimensions except the batch dimension
        num_features = 1
        for s in size:
            num_features *= s
        return num_features


net = Net()
print(net)

net = Net()
input = torch.randn(1, 1, 32, 32)
out = net(input)
print(out)
```

Why is the method forward() not explicitely called? I mean how does just calling net(output) calls forward() ? (which is what happens as far as I understand)
By the way I dont understand what this line means:

```
super(Net, self).__init__()
```

I can imagine super() is calling the constructor of a parent class but …?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you look at the `Module` [implementation](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py) of pyTorch, you'll see that forward is a method called in the special method `__call__` :

```
class Module(object):
   ...
   def __call__(self, *input, **kwargs):
      ...
      result = self.forward(*input, **kwargs)
```

As you construct a `Net` class by inheriting from the `Module` class and you override the default behavior of the `__init__` constructor, you also need to explicitly call the parent's one with `super(Net, self).__init__()`.

Comment: Thanks, great answer. This is something they could have put in the comments.

Comment: But so the _\_call_\_ merhod is called by the constructor of the Module class if i understood right?

Comment: Nope, it is called when you call an instance of the class, so in the example : `out = net(input)`. See : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9663562/what-is-the-difference-between-init-and-call

Comment: I dont see any explicit call to _\call\_ if i can say  so lol

Comment: Yes, it is defined by Python's internal implementation. You may learn more on https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/03/23/python-internals-how-callables-work/ !

Comment: great thanks for your fantastic answers!